# Customizing Django User-Authentication forms

Tags: django, forms

I am a Django Newbie. I am building a django project which uses django-authentication module.

So I am using the LoginForm which generates context variables {{form.username}} and {{form.password}} for any user to login. But to make the UX better I have something like

```
    <td><input type="text" name="username"  id="" size="30" value="" class='loginput'/></td>
```

instead of the simple

```
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
```

How do i go about using input tags but still using the django-authentication backend forms? I also understand that for any other form I could possibly use widgets, form-media. I am not able to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Why does that enhance usability? The only difference is that you've added a `class`, and for some reason *removed* the `id` attribute, therefore making it impossible to use a `label`. I can't see any circumstances under which making something less accessible would make the UX better. And removing the dynamic ability of Django forms to re-display the wrong values in case of validation failure similarly seems hardly a step forward.

I can't really understand what your question is asking, though. If you really want to use this less-usable markup in your template, why not just do it? You have to provide the template for the contrib.auth views in any case, so there's your opportunity.

Of course a much better way is to simply subclass the LoginForm and add your HTML class there:

```
class LoginForm(auth.forms.AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'loginput'}))
```

and pass this form in the extra context to the login url:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
      {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
```